# Adding .tif files with various bit depths to a raster mosaic

Tags: raster, image-mosaic, bit-depth

So I have a few georeferenced .tif files that I need to add to a raster mosaic, however the problem is that some of these are 8 bit unsigned TIFFs while others are 1 bit unsigned.  After adding all the TIFFs into the mosaic, the 1 bit TIFFs display as a black square, while the 8 bit TIFFs display normally.  Is there a way to have all TIFFs display properly regardless of bit depth?  I sort of got it working by changing the image properties to display as a stretched values rather than RGB composite, but this makes all the colour TIFFs black and white which is not ideal.  Any ideas?